# Crear Programa creando un .bat

Tags: linux, cmd, batch

Hola chicos podrian ayudarme trato de generar un path no soy muy bueno con linux 
Quiero leer dos rutas para exportar la db que primero llame al primer link y despues llame al segundo asi sucesivamente podrian ayudarme

path1 = '..\Documents\instrumentmanufacturer.cql'
path2 = '..\Documents\instrumentmanufacturer.cql'
start cqlsh -k fsainstqual -e "COPY instrumentmanufacturer (id,createdby,createdtime,description,lastmodifiedby,lastmodifiedtime,name) to %path1%"
call start cqlsh -k fsainstqual -e "COPY instrumentmodel (id,createdby,createdtime,description,lastmodifiedby ,lastmodifiedtime,manufacturerid,name) to %path2%"
exit

Comment: Esto no se ve como algo propio de Linux, sino del `cmd` de windows.

Comment: bueno la verdad no se si sea linux o cmd pero no se si puedan echarme la mano para generar un .bat

Comment: ***la verdad no se si sea linux o cmd*** Hay una gran diferencia. Primero debes establecer que ambiente usas. En principio, por el código que pones, da la impresión que usas *Windows*. Si es así, quita las referencias a la etiqueta `Linux` y coloca las de `Windows`.

Comment: No te preocupes mauricio gracias por tu ayuda ya logre crearlo :)